# Setting order of accesibility labels in subviews of a group, read aloud by Voiceover?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel, accessibility

I have a UITableView with cells based on an XIB with UIStackViews containing UILabels, in it. Labels have the texts A,B,C,D
 (look at screenshot).

[image]

When I enable VoiceOver or use the Accesibility Inspector, It automaticallly groups the labels in a cell, reading all the texts on the labels - that's fine.

But I want it to change the order that it reads the sub-labels, when the superview is focused, so it's read like A,B,C,D - currently it's A,C,B,D.

I've tried a lot of things with no luck, like overriding the accesibilityElements, shouldGroup... and isAccessiblityElement. Every time I change something, i get either:

- No change
- Empty accesiblity label for the cell
- The single labels become selectable (which is not what I wanted)

Any tips on how to fix this one? I guess I can't be the only one in the world with this problem, but apparently it's hard to find any info on recent iOS versions. I use 10.3 and Swift 3...

Answer (score 2):

I gave up on the idea of profiting form iOS own concatenation of the subviews' accesibility labels and made a piece of code to handle it myself.

```
extension UIView {
    open func updateCombinedAccessibilityLabel (elements: [AnyObject]) {
        let accLabels: [String] = elements.map { $0.accessibilityLabel ?? "" }
        accessibilityLabel = accLabels.joined(separator: ", ")
    }
}
```

Then, when I set the labels' text values, I tell the view how to arrange the subviews' accesiblity order:

```
view.updateCombinedAccessibilityLabel(elements: [view.titleLabel, view.subtitleLabel, view.detailsLabel])
```